# @AllArgsConstructor and Constructor Injection with Spring: is private final needed?

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, lombok, constructor-injection

Let's say I have the following constructor injection (not Autowiring):

```
@Service
public class FooService {

    private final OrderService orderService;

    public FooService(OrderService orderService) {
        this.orderService = orderService;
    }
}
```

That can be replaced with:

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class FooService {

    private final OrderService orderService;

}
```

Do I *need* to declare this as `private` and `final` to inject this service?  Does Lombok take care of this like they do with `@Data` and beans?  Any side-effects?

Comment: where do you see static?

Comment: `@AllArgsConstructor` using Lombok, will generate a constructor for setting all the declared (not final, not static) fields.

Comment: @Adrian, didn't intend to include static as part of the question.  Removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://projectlombok.org/features/constructor)

> `@AllArgsConstructor` generates a constructor with 1 parameter for each field in your class. Fields marked with `@NonNull` result in null checks on those parameters.

So, no, it does not make your fields `private` & `final` as for example `@Value` annotation.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `@RequiredArgsConstructor` instead, you need a single *primary* constructor to fill the required fields. So you marked them `final` and use this annotation to generate a primary constructor.
`@AllArgsConstructor` is bug-prone, because it may produce multiple constructors which Spring may fail to handle.
In your particular case the results of `@AllArgsConstructor` and `@RequiredArgsConstructor` just happen to be the same, because you have just one `final` field.

Note that, Spring documentation encourages the usage of constructor-based injection (https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-setter-injection), and recommends to avoid using several injection techniques together.

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class FooService {

    private final OrderService orderService;

}
```